# Calling fallocate() on a C++ ofstream

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am writing a large binary output buffer through ofstream::write(). Since I know the size of the output file, but sometimes have to write it in chunks, I thought it would be a good idea to call fallocate() (or posix_fallocate()) first to preallocate the buffer on disk. Those do, however, require a file descriptor, which ofstream does not provide me with.

Is there an ofstream interface for calling fallocate(), or possibly to get the underlying file descriptor so that I can call it myself? (Or is it not worth the bother?)

Comment: fallocate is, AFAICT, not meant as a performance optimization, but as a means to ensure that sufficient disk space is available before starting to write. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I was thinking of using it for performance reasons, as I am going to write such files often (several times per second), and want to optimize file system access for them by providing the final file size beforehand.

Comment: If you want performance (and you know the size of the file), then I would use memory mapped files. There have been several discussions on "how to get the best out of filesystem", and the conclusion every time is to use memory mapped files - the main reason is that this is about as efficient as you can get for loading the data into your process, and the OS can optimize the block size and such to align well with the memory it goes into, rather than the traditional file interfaces that often read too small, or too large blocks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you going to write in chunks use fwrite 
also see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/ to control buffer size 
to optimize you can have buffer size = N * chunk size